# A better way of formatting equations in plot legends

Tags: legending, plot-themes

Maybe this is a bit of trivial question, but here goes. I often think it is convenient to label a plot legend with an actual function - especially if it is a fit to some data or something.

Typically I will use something like:

`PlotLegends ->Placed[{"y = mx + c"}, {Left, 0.86}, Pane[#, 450, Alignment ->Left] &]`

Or make use of `HoldForm[...]` if I need pieces of the equation to look a certain way.

Which will work, but often renders in a way that the subscripts, in particular will merged with the fraction line/bar.

Does anyone have a better way of representing equations and formulae in a plot legend. Perhaps there is a way to use LaTeX?

Comment: Have you seen `PlotLegends -> "Expressions"`?

Comment: ...or `TraditionalForm`..., e.g., `PlotLegends -> TraditionalForm[y = Subscript[m , 1] x + b]`.

Comment: If you really want to insert LaTeX, you might want to check out [MaTeX](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/latex-typesetting-in-mathematica.html).

Comment: Ah great! I didn't know about these functions - thanks all!